# $VIMRUNTIME and $VIM variable for precompiled nvim binary

Tags: neovim

I downloaded the latest `neovim` binary from https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.3.1, and everything works fine except that the `$VIMRUNTIME` variable and `$VIM` variable are always set to some random folder inside `/tmp`. I want to use some of the files there. Is it possible to persist the runtime files? 
Moreover, is the contents inside the random `$VIMRUNTIME` folder regenerated every time I launch a new `nvim` instance?

I know that if I build `neovim` by myself and install it, then the `$VIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME` will point to a folder installed, like `INSTALLDIR/share/nvim/runtime`. But now I used precompiled binary and where should I set the $VIM and $VIMRUNTIME?

Comment: see `:help $VIM` and `:help $VIMRUNTIME`

Comment: @Sergio, I read that already. I know I can set the environment variables manually in my shell. But to what they should be set? I downloaded the nvim.appimage from the website, but they do not provide the runtime files for downloading.

Comment: Have your tried to set the enviromental variables in your shell? In bash you could do `VIM=/usr/share/nvim/; export VIM`.

Comment: I don't have that folder, can I set it?

Answer (score 0):

So I myself struggled with this specific issue for around two weeks right now.

The dreaded/ notorious: vim.diagnostics not found.

The solution as I discovered is to set the VIMRUNTIME env variable to **usr/local/share/nvim/runtime**